# How to reduce beer belly

Tags: exercise, cardio, stomach, alcohol

I regulary do between 1 - 2 hours of Cardio (usually on 'Wave' machine, Cross Trainer or Stepper) most week days and then long walks at the weekend but don't seem to be able to lose much weight or lose my beer belly, I eat healthy but am partial to drinking beer/wine at the weekends. I wouldn't consider myself over weight but would just like to burn off a bit of flab (small beer belly) without cutting out the alcohol. Any tips?

Comment: To lose weight, burn more calories than you take in. Assuming a healthy, balanced diet: Eat Less, Move More.

Answer (score 2):

Most of us think we are eating healthy.  However, without tracking what you eat (and drink), it’s mostly a guess.  And, while there’s **no way** to spot reduce your “small beer belly”, you can drop excess weight by consuming less calories than you expend.  But, in order to do that, you first need to know how many calories you are consuming on a daily basis.  Pay particular attention to excess non-essential calories (ie. alcohol) and portion size.

If you’ve read any other posts on this site, you’ll see that a common theme is to keep a food journal for a few weeks.  Doing that will give you a more accurate picture of your caloric intake rather than guessing.  Having that bit of knowledge then allows you to make the necessary calorie reductions to affect a weight loss.

Lastly, all of us have some guilty pleasure that we find hard to give up.  Rather than a total restriction, think about cutting back.  For instance, pick one day per week to consume alcohol, or, any other guilty pleasure.  At that rate, your diet would be spot on 85% of the time.